my chart does not load when using wire:navigate livewire
I have a problem, when using wire navigate, the graph does not load

but changing pages using wire:navigate remains blank

Js:
https://pastebin.com/jwYFyB3e code
the code is long, I leave the link

You're relying on wrong events:
    document.addEventListener('livewire:navigated', () => {
        console.log('Livewire navigated.');
        jQuery(document).ready($ => {
 
            $(window).on('load', function() {

The docs specifically state to use livewire:navigated over DOMContentLoaded because when you use wire:navigate, the body gets replaced, so no new page load happens and thus the page is already loaded. Therefore, the ready script will never execute. Just use the main wrapping livewire:navigated listener and nothing else.

I have it applied to document.addEventListener('livewire:navigated', () => { in the js code that I left in the post, but it still doesn't work
